# realloc cause incorrect checksum for freed object

Tags: c, sockets, memcpy, realloc

this is a part of my socket client , receive buffer is small than server's send buffer, so I need to realloc buffer, but it throw error like this:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x7fd44ad00018: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
```

my code :

```
char recv_buf[MAX_RECV_LINE] = "";
while (fgets(buf, MAX_SEND_LINE, stdin) != NULL) {  
    write(servfd, buf, strlen(buf));
    char *recv_data = malloc(MAX_RECV_LINE);
    bzero(recv_data, MAX_SEND_LINE);
    int recv_size = 0;
    while (1) {
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
        FD_SET(servfd, &readfds);
        select(servfd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
        if (FD_ISSET(servfd, &readfds)) {
            bzero(recv_buf, MAX_RECV_LINE);
            size_t recv_buf_len = recv(servfd, recv_buf, MAX_RECV_LINE, 0);
            if (recv_buf_len == 0) {
                printf("Server is closed.\n");
                close(servfd);
                exit(0);
            }

            recv_data = realloc(recv_data, recv_size + recv_buf_len);
            if (recv_data == NULL) {
                exit(0);
            }
            printf("realloc: %lu\n", recv_size + recv_buf_len);
            memcpy(recv_data + recv_size, recv_buf, recv_buf_len);

            recv_size += recv_buf_len;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("total count: %d\n", recv_size);
    printf("Message: %s", recv_data);
    free(recv_data);
}
```

and recv_data can't get the completely message

Comment: Offhand, I don't see any scribbling. But the `memcpy` call could be writing outside the allocated object, that might explain the message. Carefully check the various arguments for sanity.

Comment: How is your `recv_buf` defined?

Comment: char recv_buf[8] = "";

Comment: Is `recv_data` null-terminated?

Comment: recv_data only have a part of message send from server

Comment: Failure during free() usually means buffer overrun or bad pointer earlier in the program. Finding exactly when that happened can be a major challenge. A debugging heap implementation, if you have one available, may help. If you have a debugger that supports watchpoints, that may help too. But you may find that the only solution is to grovel through the code until you figure out what you've done wrong.

Comment: ok,I'll try to debug it.

Comment: @user2741608 Pleas do not change the code in your question, this will invalid others' answers and make the latter readers completely confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *recv_data = malloc(MAX_RECV_LINE);
bzero(recv_data, MAX_SEND_LINE);
```

The problem is here. You're allocating a buffer of size `MAX_RECV_LINE` but zeroing it for a length of `MAX_SEND_LINE`, which you said is greater. You don't need to zero it at all actually: your code appears to deal with the received data correctly. Just remove the `bzero()` call completely.

But it would be a lot simpler to use the same buffer size at both ends. I always use 8192.

Comment: @NikSun Don't be embarassed, we're computer programmers, we make mistakes every day. It's an experimental science as well as an analytic one.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

- You don't check if `recv_buf_len` is negative (e.g. from a signal). And its type should be `ssize_t`, not `size_t`.
- IIRC, you need to redo `timeout` each time you call `select` (but this wouldn't be the cause of the problem).

Comment: not check recv_buf_len because the server will reply the same message which I send to.